# Why did these magnetic ball bearings corrode?

Tags: corrosion

Before the pandemic, I bought a set of magnetic ball bearings (a few mm in diameter) and attached them to a side panel of my desk (presumably, the panel is iron coated in grey paint).

On returning to the office, I found that the ball bearings are badly corroded (more specifically, it looks like the *interior* of the bearings have corroded, with an outside coating flaking off).

What happened? Was there some kind of sacrificial oxidation of the ball interiors (even though the paint presumably insulates the bearings from the desk)?

It's not impossible that some kind of cleaning fluid was sprayed on the bearings at some point, though other ball bearings nearby (on a non-magnetic part of the desk) are still pristine.

[image: Photo of the corroded ball bearings]

Comment: They appear to be plated, maybe with nickel, and made of some inexpensive magnetized metal or ceramic. Perhaps put on safety glasses, and crush one of the bad ones with pliers, to see if it is metal or ceramic.

Comment: These magnets are usually NdFeB ceramics coated with something like nickel. So what you are seeing is not so much the corrosion of the magnet but the breakup or corrosion of the surface coating, revealing the ceramic inside. The coatings are fragile and easily corroded or disrupted. So the effect is common as plenty of things can disrupt the thin coating on the outside.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I agree some electrochemical corrosion occurring.

Per the picture, there is especially evidence of corrosion in particular spots, for example, at the end.

My guess is that one of the contributing factors is your touching the ball resulting in the deposit of NaCl. With a change in temperature and humidity, you likely fostered the creation of an electrolyte. The only missing ingredient is a weak acid, perhaps CO2 or a vinegar mist as a result of, yes, someone cleaning your desktop.

Now, [ScienceDirect notes](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/galvanic-corrosion#:%7E:text=The%20rate%20of%20the%20galvanic,be%20a%20higher%20corrosion%20rate), to quote:

> The rate of the galvanic corrosion depends on the relative surface areas and the corrosion potentials of the anode and cathode.

which suggests oxygen-rich air was the cathode, with your low surface area metal undergoing anodic corrosion with added salt and an acid source.

[Interestingly, per a source](https://www.zerust.com/blog/2019/10/02/the-cost-of-corrosion/), to quote:

> To put it simply, the total cost of corrosion across the globe is astronomical. It adds up to an estimated $2.5 trillion (USD), and that number doesn’t even include individual safety or environmental consequences, according to the report.

So, you apparently made but a small contribution to the annual global cost of galvanic corrosion.